# Remove Sprite when the Player come over it

Tags: android, andengine

This was my first attempt:

```
.......
.......
OTHER CODE
// ===========================================================
// Inner and Anonymous Classes
// ===========================================================
private  class Ball extends AnimatedSprite {
private final PhysicsHandler mPhysicsHandler;

public Ball(final float pX, final float pY, final TiledTextureRegion pTextureRegion, final VertexBufferObjectManager pVertexBufferObjectManager) {
    super(pX, pY, pTextureRegion, pVertexBufferObjectManager);
    this.mPhysicsHandler = new PhysicsHandler(this);
    this.registerUpdateHandler(this.mPhysicsHandler);
}

@Override
protected void onManagedUpdate(final float pSecondsElapsed) {
    /* Get the scene-coordinates of the players feet. */
    final float[] playerFootCordinates = this.convertLocalToSceneCoordinates(16, 16);

    int foodX = ((int) playerFootCordinates[Constants.VERTEX_INDEX_X]) / 20;
    int foodY = ((int) playerFootCordinates[Constants.VERTEX_INDEX_Y]) / 20;


    final TMXTile tmxTile = tmxLayer.getTMXTileAt(playerFootCordinates[Constants.VERTEX_INDEX_X], playerFootCordinates[Constants.VERTEX_INDEX_Y]);

    if (tmxTile.getGlobalTileID() == 2){
        final EngineLock engineLock = mEngine.getEngineLock();
        engineLock.lock();

        /* Now it is save to remove the entity! */
        scene.detachChild(food[foodX][foodY]);
        food[foodX][foodY].dispose();
        food[foodX][foodY] = null;

        engineLock.unlock();
    }
      // OTHER CODE
       ......
 }
```

but it doesn't work ("java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid location blabla, size is blabla"

i've read that:
WARNING: This function (detachChild) should be called from within RunnableHandler.postRunnable(Runnable) which is registered to a Scene or the Engine itself, because otherwise it may throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException in the Update-Thread or the GL-Thread!

so how i can remove sprite when my player come over it?

ps: i've seen SpriteRemoveExample, but it doesn't help me in my case

Answer (score 2):

Following way you can remove your sprite safely, that does not fire any ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException.

```
    mActivity.runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            clearUpdateHandlers();
            clearEntityModifiers();
            clearTouchAreas();
            detachSelf();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can do:

First, register an update handler for your scene.

Every time the player collides with a sprite, add that sprite to a list of sprites that need to be removed.

In the update handler, go through that list, and remove them exactly how you did.